# Managing global settings in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I need to manage some global parameters, which are basically just a set of key-value-pairs. My requirements are the following:

1. Initial values are read from a server config file.
2. Parameters are available in every controller for both reading/writing and adding/deleting (like a new parameter can be added if certain controller is executed).
3. Parameters should surface subsequent request (either residing in `Session` or serialized in `QueryString`).
4. I should be possible to see and easily manage them (CRUD) using a special admin webpage.

My "brute force" approach for this would be just to implement a static class with `List<Tuple<string,string>>` to keep the settings, use `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` to populate initial values, use static properties to store and retrieve the list in a session variable and design a separate controller and view for managing the settings.

But this looks like re-inventing the wheel to me. Is there any (not necessarily full-fledged) pre-existing solution (in ASP.NET, or as a NuGet package) I might rest my efforts upon? Or maybe I am missing something fundamental in ASP.NET?

**UPDATE**: Depending on the nature of the parameter, some of them might have the lifetime of the `Application`, whereas some of them are bound to the current user session. Therefore they need to be either preserved in a `Session` object or "passed through" in every request.

Comment: If they are global parameters that apply to all, then I would use `Application` instead of `Session`

Comment: So these key value pairs are temporary? They are lost once the visitor session ends?

Comment: @sunil I updated my question to address your commentary.

Comment: Why do you use List<Tuple<>> instead of Dictionary<>? are settings keys aren't unique?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov No, they are unique. I want to use `List<Tuple<>>` just in order to simplify the dynamic generation of view for CRUD operations by providing an `Enumerable<Tuple<>>` model to the view.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the most common approach, I don't see anything wrong with using session variables.